# binding ip addresses statically in /etc/network

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04

I have a 138.128.111.176/29 IP that is assigned to my server and the IP is 138.128.111.176, when I do the following in my /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface p2p1 inet static
        address 138.128.111.177
        netmask 255.255.255.248

iface p2p1 inet static
        address 138.128.111.178
        netmask 255.255.255.248

iface p2p1 inet static
        address 138.128.111.179
        netmask 255.255.255.248

iface p2p1 inet static
        address 138.128.111.180
        netmask 255.255.255.248

iface p2p1 inet static
        address 138.128.111.181
        netmask 255.255.255.248

iface p2p1 inet static
        address 138.128.111.182
        netmask 255.255.255.248
```

to make the binding permanent it did not work, I tried restarting the server etc... however when I do the following:

```
ip address add 138.128.111.178 dev p2p1
```

it worked like a charm, what did I do wrong here ?

Comment: It really isn't clear how that range assigned to your computer.  Does the machine have another IP address in addition to that range?  Is that subnet being routed to you via that public address?

Answer (score 1):

That IP is not valid with that netmask. You can only use 5 of the 8 addresses. The sixth is the gateway, which you also can't use. And the first and last addresses in the block also aren't usable, as they are the network and broadcast addresses respectively.

Comment: what is the gateway ? you mean 138.128.111.181 ?

Comment: @user79356 The gateway is which IP that your provider told you it is.

Comment: I revised it to the above and it still did not work

Comment: @user79356 It  still won't work until you find out which is your gateway, and stop trying to assign it as an IP address and assign it as the `gateway` instead.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by 'stop trying to assign it as an IP address and assign it as the gateway instead' , isn't the gateway supposed to be the sixth (you said above it was the sixth)?

Comment: @user79356 I did not say the gateway was the sixth address. I said it was the address that your ISP gave you.

Comment: Its not always the 6th address in any block, its usually address before the broadcast but there is no rule, as Mr Hampton suggests you need this info from provider. Without the gateway there is no way out for non-local traffic. Is the assigned address visible in ifconfig output after restarting ? If its failed on that level its different issue not just addressing.